# div shifts after jquery scale effect

Tags: jquery, scale

I have a div that after scaling, shifts to the left and down and I can't see why this is happening. See http://jsfiddle.net/7A7gs/2 for all code.

I've tried using animate width/height instead of scale, and the same thing happens. I've also tried size instead of scale. Same thing.

Also, if I change the scale from 'both' to vertical, the div does *not* shift. If I change the scale to 'horizontal' the div shifts.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong here! MTIA.

EDIT:  The desired behaviour is that the clicked div shifts to the top left corner of the window (this is currently working correctly), then expands to fill the width and height of the window.

Currently, it expands to fill the width and height of the window and then shifts downward and to the left, which is *not* the desired behaviour.

Comment: do you want all the div's to be placed in a single row ?

Comment: What's the desired behaviour when a div is clicked?

Comment: I want the clicked div to move to the top left corner and expand/grow downwards and to the right, which will fill the window.

Comment: I can't get it to reproduce the error in Chrome 14 Dev. It moves the div to the top left, then scales in the vertical... It doesn't scale in the horizontal as the jsFiddle doesn't tell it to do that

Comment: my apologies then, it should use 'both', not 'vertical'. see http://jsfiddle.net/7A7gs/2/ for code using 'both'

Comment: @circey: ok, I can get it to repro now. Will investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it appears that the offset positioning was causing the problem. I changed the code to switch between relative and absolute positioning and the animation stopped jumping.

Answer (score 0):

this is a known bug,
please read here for a quick fix and a solution:
[Element jumps to wrong position after "scale" effect](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4316)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unable to get the fix to work. In addition, I wasn't using origin in my code. If you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/42U8c/ it uses 'middle'/'center' and it certainly reproduces the problem I'm having. However, if you change the fiddle to use 'top' and 'left', the scale works perfectly. See here for my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7A7gs/29/ which uses both 'top' and 'left', yet the error is still occurring.