# jquery function won't run on previously clicked div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scale

This question is related to [this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434354/div-shifts-after-jquery-scale-effect).  Please see current [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3CnvN/1/).

I've been able to get it working so that the clicked div scales and animates nicely. But I now have 2 other problems:

1. Once the clicked div has been scaled back to original size, the script won't run when I click the same div again to repeat the action.
2. I'm not really happy with the jumpy rescaling/repositioning. I can't seem to get it to work as smoothly. I guess I'd be okay with it as is, but I'd be a lot happier if it was as smooth as the initial scale/animation.

Please let me know if I need to be clearer.

Any assistance would be much appreciated! MTIA.

Comment: Not sure about your problem of it not working the second time, but the animations seem very smooth to me. Perhaps it's just your browser and/or overloaded resources? (cpu and ram)

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Fair point. Up until yesterday I had been posting code *solely* in the question, but thought perhaps it might be easier for people to look on jsfiddle! In future, I'll be sure to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work a second time because you remove the `click` handler from it when making it not current anymore:

```
selectedBox.unbind('click');
```

That unbinds *all* click handlers from the div, including the one you hooked up in `ready` initially.

Four options:

1. <s>Don't unbind the main click, and use jQuery's event "namespacing" for the second click event:</s>

   ```
   $('.current').bind('click.current', function() {
   ```

   ...and then when unbinding:

   ```
   selectedBox.unbind('click.current');
   ```

   Be sure to stop the event in the current click handler, so the main click handler isn't run (jQuery makes sure handlers are run in reverse order of being hooked up, so you know the current handler will run before the main handler, cross-browser). Never mind, sorry, it's the other way around: jQuery ensures they run in the order they were bound, not reverse order.
2. <s>Use a named function for the current click event:</s>

   ```
   $('.current').click(currentClick);
   function currentClick() {
   ```

   ...and remove it specifically:

   ```
   selectedBox.unbind('click', currentClick);
   ```

   ...and again, don't remove the main handler.
3. Use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) rather than `click` for the main (non-current) click:

   ```
   $('#content').delegate('.box', 'click', boxClickHandler);
   ```

   That hooks up the `click` event on the container of the boxes, not the boxes themselves, and then responds to clicks because they bubble.

   In your "current" click handler, be sure to cancel the click event so it doesn't bubble up to the container.

   [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CnvN/2/) with that change implemented. I also namedspaced the "current" click just to be friendly to any other code that might also need to know when a box is clicked.
4. Put the `boxClickHandler` back after removing the current click handler:

   ```
   selectedBox.unbind('click').click(boxClickHandler);
   ```
5. Use a single handler and branch within the handler depending on whether you see the "current" class on the box.

...or some combination of the above.

I like #5 the best.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add the unbind because I needed to be able to click a second time on the div to close/shrink it. I think I'm going about that wrong and perhaps it would be best to simply add an id or swap the class.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted Mr. Crowder's response but after playing around with your jFiddle it seems there's a far less round about way to do all of this using the .toggle() method

Instead of adding and removing click events to an element after you change the class name, just make the same element do a different action on its second click.  This could really save you a lot of work.  Something that would start like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').toggle(click1,click2);
});
function click1(){
    $('.box').not(this).animate({left:2000},1000);
}
function click2(){
    $('.box').not(this).animate({left:0},1000);
}
```

Comment: Gosh, that's a lovely way of doing it. I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick look, and maybe just need to fix the sequencing as in **chaining the events**.
I clicked the box while it was animated and it shrunk and shrunk then everything failed.

Other than that you animation is **absolutely awesome!**